# How to center align text horizontally from coordinate/point

Tags: html

CSS `text-align: center;` property can align your text to be centered.

However, what if you want the text to be centered based of a point? Like on a canvas?

On a canvas to do this, you simply place the text at a coordinate and set its `textAlign` property to centered.

Here is how to do it in a normal html div...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like the text centered from the point `50%, 200px`, here is how you would do it:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1"> This text is centered at 50%, 200px </div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1 {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0px;

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100px; /* height of text */
}
```

Optional: `pointer-events: none; /* this prevents pointer events, so divs behind it are clickable. */`

---

If you want a different point, set the CSS to the following:

`top:` px from top of screen
 `;`

`left: 0px;`

`width:` (px or percentage from left of screen) * 2 `;`

`height:` px for height `;`